# how to add calculated columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ip-address

I have a Pandas dataframe with a set of IP rules.  The rules themselves are IPv4 CIDR addresses stored as strings, so might cover one IP or might cover many, and there are also rule name and priority columns.  I'd like to sort this dataframe first by the rule priority, then by the number of IPs covered by the rules.  I've tried a couple of approaches using the `IPv4Network` class from the `ipaddress` module:

- `.sort_values()` with `key=lambda x: IPv4Network(x.str()).num_addresses`, and several other variants
- add a calculated column using that same `IPv4Network(df['Rule']).num_addresses` logic, and can't get it to work- eg   `finalrules = finalrules.assign(num_addresses=lambda x: IPv4Network(x['Rule']).num_addresses)`

I'm getting exceptions from the `IPv4Network` class, suggesting that perhaps I'm not getting the string back out from the dataframe?  Somehow this method also seems to drop columns from the dataframe, and I'm only left with the `Rule` column at the end.  Should I just iterate item by item, or do I need to write a function that understands operating on a column, or how to I fix this?  I feel like I'm lacking knowledge about what `.assign` actually does.

Answer (score 0):

And as usual, list expressions to the rescue.

`finalrules['num_addresses'] = [IPv4Network(rule).num_addresses for rule in finalrules['Rule']]`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).